# How to change indication of smart pointer

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I want to make my own list, based on smart pointers.
I want a function which I can add value in my list, but I don't know how to change the value of the variable `next` in the object passed to function to point to the newly created object. Someone has an idea?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct node
{
    int value;
    std::unique_ptr<node> next;

    node() {
        value = 0;
        next = nullptr;
    }
};

void add(std::unique_ptr<node> &w, int liczba)
{
    std::unique_ptr<node> new_list_node{ new node };
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<node> list_node{ new node };
    add(list_node, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign

```
void add(std::unique_ptr<node> &w, int liczba)
{
    std::unique_ptr<node> new_list_node{ new node };
    w->next = std::move(new_list_node);
}
```

Or better yet, for c++14

```
void add(std::unique_ptr<node> &w, int liczba)
{
    w->next = std::make_unique<node>();
}
```

You just have to make sure you either assign an rvalue to `next` or cast an lvlaue to an rvalue reference with `std::move`

Comment: How would he pass the tail every time to the `add` function if only one unique ptr can point to an object?

Comment: @PetarVelev - Like he already does, by passing a **reference** to a `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: but he must keep track of the tail to be able to pass that reference. And if he cannot create another `unique_ptr` to the tail because the second last element already holds the unique ownership of the object?

Comment: @PetarVelev - He can refer to each `next` field indirectly, `std::unique_ptr<node>*`. Just takes thinking in more than a single indirection. The ownership has nothing to do with how one traverses the list.

Comment: Yeah i know that he can use the next field. I was just wondering  how would he keep the track of the tail on which he want to add a new node without having to iterate trough the whole list to get the last unique pointer which points to nothing.

Comment: @PetarVelev - That's quite a broad question. But like I said, keeping non-owning raw pointer and updating it in a loop is always possible.